# Youtube API v3, topicId and freebase

Tags: php, youtube-api

So I am trying to pull out videos from Youtube for specific video games. This I have working almost fine, however on querying the video game title, some (mostly ones that share names with sports franchises, films, etc) are coming back with non video game related results.

I have looked in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and found the topicId filter, however I am struggling to use it.

If I try to put something in it comes back with:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->list(array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'part' => 'id',
  'order' => 'relevance',
  'type' => 'video',
  'topicId' => '/m/0d6lp'
));
```

> (list) unknown parameter: 'topicId'

Also having trouble using the freebase API to return a topic I need.

All I want to do is filter videos only with the following:
[image: Youtube video category as 'gaming']

So any ideas how I limit youtube searches to video games only with the search api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example looks a little off.  The release of the PHP client might not be updated for the YouTube release, but the code is checked it.  Head to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ and checkout the source to get an up to date version after that this code should work fine.

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
  'order' => 'relevance',
  'type' => 'video',
  'topicId' => '/m/0d6lp'
));
```

Call `listSearch` instead of `list`, and put the `part` as the first argument instead of in the array.

Comment: I think I overcomplicated things a bit, dont need freebase, I can just do a video/list on the ids returned by the search/list and filter the categoryId as 20 which is gaming. thanks for the answer anyways